# Weird character sequence in email subject

Tags: email, vulnerability, known-vulnerabilities, encoding, smtp

I've noticed that the subject in one of the spam emails looks like this in source:

```
Subject: Offe=?UTF-8?Q?=EF=BB=BF?=r fr=?UTF-8?Q?=EF=BB=BF?=om C=?UTF-8?Q?=EF=BB=BF?=redi=?UTF-8?Q?=EF=BB=BF?=t On=?UTF-8?Q?=EF=BB=BF?=e Ba=?UTF-8?Q?=EF=BB=BF?=nk=?UTF-8?Q?=EF=BB=BF?==?UTF-8?Q?=EF=BB=BF?=
```

but in web it looks normal

```
Offer from Credit One Bank
```

The only thing I recognize is `0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF`, which is the UTF-8 BOM.

Which interpreter recognizes this character sequence `=?UTF-8?Q?=EF=BB=BF?=` ?

Is there a vulnerability around email subjects? What are they trying to do?

Comment: They're trying to obfuscate the email from being detected by spam filters.

Comment: Rather than editing your answer into your question, you should [self-answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) formatting and it is required in email because [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) (.eml, originally RFC 822) explicitly allows only [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters, so [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) presents an "ASCII-armor" (to [borrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AASCII_armor) a term from PGP) format to encode non-ASCII text as either quoted-printable or [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

This is formatted like `=?CHARSET?ENCODING?CONTENT?=`

Quoted-printable is particularly useful for when the content is mostly ASCII, so for example `Chris España` could be encoded as `=?UTF-8?Q?Chris=20Espa=F1a?=` rather than base64's longer and less human-legible `=?UTF-8?B?Q2hyaXMgRXNwYcOxYQ==?=`

As discussed in the comments and the other answer, this is an obfuscation technique. In this case, it's using "zero-width no-break space" characters (U+FEFF, aka ZWNBSP or BOM, represented in UTF-8 as `0xEF` `0xBB` `0xBF`, which Unicode has deprecated in favor of [word joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_joiner), U+2060). According to that Wikipedia page:

> Character U+FEFF is intended for use as a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) (BOM) at the start of a file. However, if encountered elsewhere, it should, according to Unicode, be treated as a "zero width no-break space".

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the character sequence is legitimately used to encode UTF-8 characters in internet headers, since they can contain only ASCII (rfc1342). Here however, is used to hide from spam filters, as Ghedipunk said in a comment.